# Show that $\frac {\sin(3x)}{ \sin x} + \frac {\cos(3x)}{ \cos x} = 4\cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Show that

> $$\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin x} + \frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos x} = 4\cos(2x).$$

Comment: WOW, I didn't expect there would be so many responses to this question. Thankyou to everyone who has contributed too helping understand the fundamentals of this question, as I appreciate the purpose of the website. So thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{\sin x} + \frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos x}$$
$$\dfrac{\sin(3x)\cos x + \cos(3x)\sin x}{\cos x{\sin x}}$$
$$\dfrac {\sin (3x+x)}{\sin x\cos x}$$
$$\dfrac {\sin 4x}{\sin x\cos x}$$
$$\dfrac {2\sin 2x\cos 2x}{\sin x\cos x}$$
$$\dfrac {4\sin x\cos x\cos 2x}{\sin x\cos x}$$
$$4\cos 2x$$

Answer (score 6):

Use this fact that $$\sin(x+3x)=\sin(3x)\cos(x)+\cos(3x)\sin(x)$$

Comment: Also, $\sin(2(2x))=\sin(x+3x)$.

Comment: Nice fact to use here! +1

Comment: $\large \ddot \smile\;\heartsuit$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start
$$ \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin x} + \frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos x}=2 \frac{\cos(x)\sin(3x)+\sin(x)\cos(3x)}{\sin 2x}  = \dots. $$

Answer (score 2):

We have,

$$\sin(3x) = 3\sin(x) - 4\sin^{3}(x)$$

and

$$\cos(3x) = 4\cos^{3}(x) - 3 \cos(x).$$

Thus, your expression reduces to 
$$3 - 4\sin^{2}(x) + 4\cos^{2}(x) - 3$$

which is equal to

$$4 \cos(2x),$$

as $\cos(2x) = \cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**:

$\sin (3x) = 3\sin x - 4 \sin^3 x$

and

$\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3x - 3\cos x$

Answer (score 0):

> $$\frac {\sin3x} {\sin x} = 3-4\sin^2x$$

as $\sin3x = 3\sin x-4\sin^3x$

> $$\frac {\cos3x} {\cos x} = 4\cos^2x - 3$$

as $\cos3x = 4\cos^3x -3\cos x$

adding the two above we get $4(\cos^2x - \sin^2x)=4\cos2x.$